# What is physics field absorption with a collision object for particles?

Tags: particles, physics, collision, force-fields

I have read this information

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/physics/collision.html#bpy-types-collisionsettings

Does anyone have a better explanation in a few paragraphs?

The question arises when a particle has reached an mesh physics effector and the Blender User would like the particle to follow the surface of the mesh.   Does it change the velocity of the particle?  If an effector is both a field and an obstacle what happens?  If a particle has a velocity parallel to the surface of a mesh does that qualify as a collision? (Dot product to surface normal is zero)

Thanks.

Comment: Do some science, and find out! 

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: you made my day!!  ...although i understand atomicbezierslinger - the documentation could be better in some cases - i am often missing examples and "easier to understand" explanation